# Checkout Page Loads Without CSS Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom theme using Underscores Starter Theme.

I have installed Woocommerce( Got the messege that my theme is not compitable) , but all the pages are working just fine, except from the Cart and the Checkout page.

These 2 pages have no CSS applied as seen in the picture below.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks[image]

Comment: can you share your site url?

Comment: @vel It's on localhost that the problem, i can share my teamviewer if you want in private!

Comment: @vel can you add me on skype?  : mitsosknight

Comment: FYI the "theme not compatible" message is common with custom/barebones themes. You just need to declare woocommerce support in your theme functions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working solutions:**

1. copy the woocomerce folder from plugin add add in your current active theme folder.
2. check the checkout page template and check the page.php file thats is includes `get_header();` and `get_footer()`.